# Why do my character's feet slide when I auto-configure a humanoid rig in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, skeletal-animation, rigging

I've downloaded an FBX animation of someone walking from the "Walking" section [here](http://docs.ipisoft.com/Sample_Video_and_Project_(single_depth_sensor)).

I imported that and also a humanoid character and specified the Rig for both as Humanoid (auto-create).

The original animation has very solid foot placement, but whenever I apply it to any character in Unity the feet slide around as if it were walking on ice.

[Here is a video](https://youtu.be/Wk6LIwEJbRs) demonstrating my issue. Is there something about the way I am getting Unity to auto-rig my character that would cause this problem? It happens no matter which 3D character I use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open the Animator window for your controller, click the animation in question, tick "Foot IK" in the animation